# How do I reference a Svelte component's parent component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-2

Per the [Svelte documentation on Props](https://svelte.technology/guide#props) I am using props to pass a reference to the parent component to a child.

> Props, short for 'properties', are the means by which you pass data down from a parent to a child component

That's exactly what I want to do. Here is [a Svelte REPL with my code](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.9.7&gist=46ea919ea8c41a00615fe0e0dedc7174), that is also copied below:

My parent is **App.html**:

```
<div class='widget-container'>
    <Widget foo bar="static" {baz}/>
</div>

<script>
    import Widget from './Widget.html';

    export default {
        data: function(){ 
            return {
                baz: 'click me and check the console'
            }
        },
        components: {
            Widget
        }
    };
</script>
```

The child component is **Widget.html**:

```
<p>foo: {foo}</p>
<p>bar: {bar}</p>
<p>baz: {baz}</p>

<script>
    export default {
        oncreate: function(){
            window.document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                console.log(`Clicked!, ${baz}`)
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Thanks to the props, the HTML `<p>` elements can clearly reference the parent. However **how can I reference the values in the parent component in the child component's JavaScript?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside lifecycle hooks and methods, access state with `this.get()`:

```html
<p>foo: {foo}</p>
<p>bar: {bar}</p>
<p>baz: {baz}</p>

<script>
    export default {
        oncreate: function(){
            window.document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const { baz } = this.get();
                console.log(`Clicked!, ${baz}`)
            });
        }
    }l
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise `this.get()` travelled up to parents. 

Comment: To be specific, and to avoid confusing anyone else who sees this answer : It doesn't travel up to parents — it's getting its *own* data, but that includes `baz` because it was passed down from the parent

Comment: Hrm, it looks like that's a second copy of the data. How do I reference the parent's data, not make a second copy?

Comment: if you want to manipulate the parents data in a child component you should use bind like this in your App.html `bind:baz={baz}` or even the shorthand `bind:{baz}`